# Postfix: Enforcing outbound TLS based on sender and receipient domain?

Tags: postfix, tls

I know that it is fairly trivial to enforce TLS based on the recipient domain by using `smtpd_enforce_tls`. I have a use case where I need to enforce TLS to certain recipient domains based on the sending domain. This is to be used in a multi-tenant environment where one tenant may not care if their mail to `example.com` is sent through TLS, but another requires it's enforcement for compliance reasons. Is there any way to achieve this without having to create separate listeners for each tenant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html) it is not possible. The current implementation can only decide on the destination; and not on the source.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: no, that would require pre-routing the message before the TLS session, which defeats the purpose of using it; and there is no way to route it inside of the session either.

The long answer: you would be better off doing one of the following:

- forcing your TLS-based tenants to configure their MUA to use TLS out of the box, bypassing the entire issue.  This isn't a problem because postfix will happily have both encrypted and non-encrypted listeners running; however it obviously creates issues if the user doesn't bother to do this, because most auto-configure mail clients will probe the ports and find the unencrypted one...etc. etc. etc.
- forcing all connections to be TLS-based, which would be handled transparently for everyone anyways as you can run TLS on port 25, but not SSL.  This would be the easiest/laziest option, but I don't know your configuration or server capacity and it could be sub-optimal on a high-volume server.

Comment: The first option does not work. Even if the MUA uses TLS to communicate with the gateway MTA, the ongoing nexthops are not automatically TLS secured. And Roadgeeks wants to talk to the nexthops with TLS based to the sender.

Comment: 'Tis true that the remaining hops (if any) do not have a guarantee that they will be encrypted.  The problem is that email is predicated on having a Gentleman's Agreement to deliver mail between sites.  Once the message leaves the MUA to the MTA, there is no control over delivery, security, etc.  The best you could hope for is to pre-encrypt the message (SMIME or PGP) and send it.